# How can I achieve a higher precision than 14-bit in an analog to digital conversion (ADC)

Tags: adc, fpga

How can I achieve a higher precision than 14-bit in an analog to digital conversion (ADC) without using conventional ICs on the market?

Comment: Why don't you want to buy an IC? That will give you by far the best results. What sample rate are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 'conventional ICs on the market' achieve, less than 14 bits, 14 bits, and more than 14 bits, depending on what you buy. Are you proposing to make a discrete component design?

Answer (score 1):

Oversampling by 4 times can get you 1 more bit of resolution but, you need to process the 4 samples in your code a little bit. Oversampling by 16 times clearly gets you 2 bits extra of resolution. The statements in my answer assume that the lower order bit of your ADC has noise on it.

[INCREASE DYNAMIC RANGE OF SAR ADCS USING OVERSAMPLING](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/tech-articles/Increase-Dynamic-Range-with-SAR-ADCs-Using-Oversampling.pdf): -

[image]

Oversampling is what sigma delta ADCs do to achieve high resolution.